# Truncate DataGridView fields so it doesnt exceed 10 characters?

Tags: c#, t-sql

So I have a form that when it is opened, loads selected information from a database. However, I want to truncate the Date column, so instead of showing how

```
'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss a.m/p.m'
```

I want it to only show

```
'DD/MM/YYYY'
```

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio for my database, and was under the impression that a Date type in that didn't record the time field anyway.

My code for populating the DGV:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FarmersMarket;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader dr;

        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();

        cmd.CommandText = "Select EventID, EventDate, Location from Events";

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                int n = dgvEvents.Rows.Add();
                dgvEvents.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = dr[0].ToString();
                dgvEvents.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = dr[1].ToString();
                dgvEvents.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = dr[2].ToString();
            }
        }

        con.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be your solution but not a good solution

```
dgvEvents.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = dr[1].TrimEnd(' ').ToString();
```

Comment: Good enough :) Cheers